# Flutter UI Visual Noise and Distortion

Tags: flutter, user-interface

As I test my Flutter app on a physical Android device the UI seems to accumulate visual noise/artifacts. The distortion usually starts on the very top of the notification bar and is barely noticeable. It then spreads to other parts of the screen, but the notification bar is the most affected. Restarting the device seems to help.

Any ideas on remediation?

Comment: a screenshot may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping each page’s `Scaffold` in a `SafeArea` seems to solve the problem.